# How can I get my CAML to only return non-hidden (user created) fields without specifing every field?

Tags: caml-query, caml, camlviewfields

I can provide the ViewFields but I was wondering if there is a way to return all the user created fields (non-hidden ones) without having to do that.

I know this works:

```
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="UserCreatedField1" />
    <FieldRef Name="UserCreatedField2" />
    <FieldRef Name="UserCreatedField..." />
    <FieldRef Name="UserCreatedFieldX" />
</ViewFields>
```

But I'm hoping there is an easier way then specifying each FieldRef.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly request for each fields you want.

Comment: I'm using an extension method which generates the FieldRefs for me for a given FieldName Collection.

Comment: @Andreas Yes using custom code we can find out user fields. But I believe `IMTheNachoMan` is look for attribute which can provide this functionality out of the box.

Comment: @AmalHashim Do you have a link for me to identify user fields using code?

Comment: Yes. `SPField` has a property `FromBaseType`. If the value of that field TRUE means it is created by user.

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to work only for fields created using the ui. Do you know an other property which seperates system fields from later added fields (either ui or programmatically).

Answer (score -1):

You may first connect to list programmatically and get all feilds as collection then look for non hidden fields and you get non hidden fields collection. Then write your own caml query with collection.

Comment: I wanted to avoid first collecting a list of user created fields. For example, I can't programmatically change a DVWP SelectCommand but I don't want to have to edit it every time I add a new field.